# Dockerized Vue app - should I use docker or node env variables?

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have dockerized vue.js application and would like to know if I should store env variables inside docker, Vue config or other place?

What is the best practice for it? I hardly see the difference since I would only have 2 environments (dev and prod)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vue supports `.env` file:
from [vue-cli docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)

> You can specify env variables by placing the following files in your
>   project root:
>
> .env                # loaded in all cases

just throw it in your vue root directory.

caution -

> Only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded
>   into the client bundle

(ie inside the vue app, via `process.env`)

now, if you need other processes rather then the vue app inside the container to know those env files, you may specify the path to that env in the `env_file: path/to/.env` option in the docker-compose:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#envfile

Comment: Yes but in this case they would not share same env files right? Different roots

Comment: I have .env file that works fine in npm run serve local copy but all the variables are undefined when the app is built via gitlab pipeline